# How to restart Media player service from where it was paused?

Tags: android, service

I read docs at Android Developer and still cant pause my service and then start it from the paused state (Playing the song).

With my current code, it always restart from the beginning of the song, but I would like to restart where the song was paused (with the `stopClick`).

Now I understand problem. In the MainActivity using stopService() method fully destroys it.
So how could i say service to wait when i press stop button to pause?

The Service class:

```
  public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
    MediaPlayer player;
     int currentPos; 

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        final int MAX_VOLUME = 100;
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lightmusic);
        player.setLooping(true);
        float soundVolume = 77;
        final float volume = (float) (1 - (Math.log(MAX_VOLUME - soundVolume) / Math
                .log(MAX_VOLUME)));
        player.setVolume(volume, volume);

        player.seekTo(currentPos);
        player.start();

    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.seekTo(currentPos);
        player.start();

        return 1;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        player.seekTo(currentPos);
        player.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        player.seekTo(currentPos);
        player.start();
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }

    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {
        currentPos = player.getCurrentPosition();
         player.pause(); 

    }



    public void onPause() {
         currentPos = player.getCurrentPosition();
         player.pause(); 


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        currentPos = player.getCurrentPosition();
         player.pause(); 
        //player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }
}
```

And my main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends QuizActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class));


    }



    public void stopClick(View v) {
        stopService(new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class));
    }

    public void playClick(View v) {
        startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to somehow send the service "The Position Where the Service Stopped the player LastTime" and next time get that time and seek to that position

Comment: use resume() method of media player for play song from same position.

Comment: When do you want to play again?

Comment: Added MainActivity. I would like it to run when button clicked

Comment: May be you can save the `currentPos` when you pause media player, save that to shared preference, then on button click, retrieve that value, and start from there?

Comment: I thought about that too. But that is sure not the best way.